# Install module without the original npm installation

Tags: javascript, angular, github, npm

There is a module that I want to try and make some changes to, for a test.

The code is here:

https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid

Right now to install this in my project I just need to type: npm install angular2-grid from my terminal.

*My question is:*

If I downloaded the code from github and made some changes to it,

How do I install it in my product and test it if my test changes are not on npm repo?

Comment: I want to say [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), but I have never tried it with anything outside a library I was building myself. Worth checking into, maybe.

Comment: You can use `npm install` with github links and local paths too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Way 1: Relative Path

1. clone repo and edit the code, then build it.
2. Use it with relative path.

Done!

```
import { NgGridModule } from './angular2-grid';
```

### Way 2: `npm link`

```
cd ~/projects/angular2-grid # go into the package directory (and edit and build)
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/myProject     # go into some other package directory.
npm link angular2-grid      # link-install the package
```

### Way 3: `npm install <git repo>`

Fork and push changes to your repo and

```
npm install --save <your repo address>
```

example,

```
npm install --save https://github.com/YOURUSERNAME/angular2-grid
```

There are probably lot of other ways to deal with it. But these above will be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install npm modules locally.

Just use `npm install file:/path/to/your/repo`

Alternately, you could fork the repo and then use a github link:

`npm install github:yourname/angular2-grid.git`